# How do I search for logs with values in an array in Datadog?

Tags: parsing, logging, datadog

```
{
    dd {    
        service cm-api
    },
    level: INFO,
    product_ids: [  
        4105428,
        4105429,
        4105430,
        4105431,
    ],
    time: 2021-11-20T22:45:11.733088+00:00
}
```

I want to find all logs that have a certain product_id in them. I want something like (in pseudo-code) `@product_ids.contains(4105428)`. I have tried `@product_ids:5845542` but I don't get back logs that have this number in them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a Facet to `product_ids` already? If a field isn't faceted, then it's not readily searchable.

It's usually simplest to view a log entry with the `product_ids` value and click it, the popup should show "Create facet for product_ids" and then any new logs with that value will be searchable from that point forward.

Read more on Facets: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/facets/

Once it's faceted and searchable, you should be able to use the search syntax you've tried.

More examples: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/#arrays

Comment: so what would be the query syntax in this case? can you share an example?